# How to match text that is part exact and part variable

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I am trying to remove segments from a json file describing trading cards. In this file is card information, some of which is market data which I dont need.

I have tried something like

```
"card_price": \[(.*?)\]
```

Where

```
"card_price": \[
```

is always going to be present. But whats in between the square brackets could be different for every entry.

How can I match everything between the square brackets, as well as

```
"card_price": \[
```

Comment: That should work. Have you checked the Regex box?

Comment: Can the stuff in square brackets span multiple lines? `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

Comment: `"card_price": \[[^]]+\]`